# Get the SUM based on multiple IF Statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The need is to get the SUM for all cells `D2:K2`. The cells values are encoded, want to replace `11 by 1`, `10 or 1 by 0.5` finally `0 by 0` while performing the *sum operation*.

[image]

Below the tried formula but not working:

```
=SUM(IF(D2:K2=11,1,IF(D2:K2=10,0.5,IF(D2:K2=1,0.5,0))))
```

Need help please!

Comment: Have you tried sumif() or sumifs() ?

Comment: `=COUNTIF(D2:K2,11)+COUNTIF(D2:K2,10)/2+COUNTIF(D2:K2,1)/2`.

Comment: You may try this as well, `=SUM(COUNTIF(D2:K2,{10,1}))/2+COUNTIF(D2:K2,11)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sum of regular COUNTIF() functions ?

```
=COUNTIF(D2:K2,11)*1+COUNTIF(D2:K2,10)*0.5+COUNTIF(D2:K2,1)*0.5
```